# httpUrlConnection keep returning Not Found in Android 4.4

Tags: android, json, httpclient, httpurlconnection, android-4.4-kitkat

i'm using piece of code to get json file from server which is really exists on the server, but the httpUrlConnection keep return responseMessage "Not Found"
here is my code

```
private void openHttpUrlConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        Log.d("urlstring in parser", urlString + "");
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        httpConnection.connect();
        Log.d("connection",httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
    }
```

while when i switch to httpClient it works properly for the same url

```
private void openHttpClient(String urlString) throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

    reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
}
```

the json file url is http://aizariacouncil.org/products.json

Comment: when i tried to go here http://aizariacouncil.org/ then same problem

Comment: go to http://aizariacouncil.org/products.json, the index file in the website is corrupted right now, but the json file exists and opens in the browser,, double check it

Comment: Try to fix the problem first and only come

Comment: try it now http://aizariacouncil.org, the problem continue to occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You web server tries to redirect the request coming from mobile to another url:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://mobile.aizariacouncil.org/products.json">here</a>.</p>
 <hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.aizariacouncil.org Port 80</address>
</body></html
```

And the url where it tries to redirect gives 404. You should fix the server.